# How to model a list in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to render this HTML:

```
<div className="panel panel-default">
  <div className="panel-body">
    <dl className="dl-horizontal">
      <dt>Step 1</dt>
      <dd>
        <samp>Output 2</samp><br>
        <samp>Output 2</samp>
      </dd>
      <dt>Step 1</dt>
      <dd>
        <samp>Output 2</samp><br>
        <samp>Output 2</samp>
      </dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

The trivial way to model this in React would be:

```
var ResultBoxPanel = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="panel panel-default">
        <div className="panel-body">
          <dl className="dl-horizontal">
            <ResultBoxStep name="Step 1" />
            <ResultBoxStep name="Step 2" />
          </dl>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var ResultBoxStep = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <dt>{this.props.name}</dt>
      <dd>
        <samp>Output 1</samp><br />
        <samp>Output 2</samp>
      </dd>
    );
  }
});
```

This doesn't work because apparently I [cannot return multiple siblings](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127) from a `render` function.

So, how would I go about modeling this?

Comment: Simplest way would be to wrap the `dt` and `dd` with a `span` tag and be done with it.

Comment: I [don't think that is allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to spec, using a `span` within the `dl` tree is not allowed but according to React it most certainly is.

However in order to keep to HTML spec this would be how you should model it.

```
<ResultBoxDT title={"Step 1"}/>
<ResultBoxDD name='Step 1 dd'/>
<ResultBoxDT title="Step 2" />
<ResultBoxDD name='Step 2 dd'/>
```

And to make this a bit more dynamic this would be how you'd generate multiple sections, which, should also lead you to understand that you don't need to extract each tag to its own component.

```
{
    list.map(function(item) {
        var title = 'Step ' + item;
        var name = 'Step ' + item + ' dd';
        return [
            <ResultBoxDT title={title}/>,
            <ResultBoxDD name={name} />
        ]
    })
}
```